# Can Outlook handle more than one Macro / event handler at a time? Can I combine 2 macros into one?

Tags: vba, outlook, eventhandler

These codes, in ThisOutlookSession, work as expected when I paste them on their own, but if I try them together I get an error.

The first code below makes it so that any time I hit send on an email, I get a popup asking if I'd like to continue sending:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    If MsgBox("Do you want to continue sending the mail?", vbOKCancel) <> vbOK Then
        Cancel = True
End Sub
```

The second code below makes it so that once an email is sent (once it makes it to my sent folder) I get a popup asking if I'd like to print the email.

```
Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias _
"ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As
String, _
ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, _
ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As
Long
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
Dim Ns As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim Folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Set Ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Folder = Ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
Set Items = Folder.Items
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then
If MsgBox("Print email?", vbYesNo Or vbQuestion) = vbYes
Then
Item.PrintOut
End If
End If

End Sub
```

I would like to have the window pop when I hit send AND the second window pop after the mail is sent. I tried pasting both codes in their entirety into ThisOutlookSession. I am getting this error

[image]

Does anyone have any insight as to how I would get this to work, or if this is even possible?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Hi Chris, I get an error that says Compile Error: Expected: type name . I get the error when the application is launched, and each time I try to send an email thereafter.

Comment: Hopefully the changes below work for you.  Don't forget to accept the answer if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dropped your code into a code error and a few errors popped up.  Don't worry.  They're easy to fix.  it looks like some of the original code that was on one line was split into multiple lines and can't be properly read.  Try this:

```
Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias _
    "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, _
    ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, _
    ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long

Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items


Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    If MsgBox("Do you want to continue sending the mail?", vbOKCancel) <> vbOK Then
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub



Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim Ns As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim Folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Set Ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Folder = Ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
    Set Items = Folder.Items
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then
        If MsgBox("Print email?", vbYesNo Or vbQuestion) = vbYes _
           Then
            Item.PrintOut
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

And now for the explanation.  The following from your original code is actually 1 line of code:

```
Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias _
"ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As
String, _
ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, _
ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As
Long
```

You can split a long line of code across multiple lines with a space and an underscore at the end of a line.  There were a few areas like this where the space and underscore was missing.  You can add them to the end of the line or move the text to one row.  I did a little of both.

The same problem happened here:

```
If MsgBox("Print email?", vbYesNo Or vbQuestion) = vbYes
Then
```

This needs to be one line of code.  So both of the following will work, but the first is more common and considered easier to read:

```
If MsgBox("Print email?", vbYesNo Or vbQuestion) = vbYes Then
```

...which is identical to

```
If MsgBox("Print email?", vbYesNo Or vbQuestion) = vbYes _
Then
```

Lastly, the parts that aren't "subs", like "Private Declare..." and "Private WithEvents..." need to be at the top of the script, above all the subs.

Comment: thanks Chris. I tried that and am getting Compile error: only comments may appear after end sub, end function , or end property.

Comment: I will paste the original code again in case the first didn't come over correctly

Comment: Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    If MsgBox("Do you want to continue sending the mail?", vbOKCancel) <> vbOK Then
        Cancel = True
End Sub

Comment: well that didn't go over well.

Comment: Move the "Private Declare" and "Private WithEvents" lines to the top of the code, above all the "subs".  Usually anything that isn't a "sub" has to go at the top of your script.  i just tested it and it works!

Comment: Hallelujah!! Chris you are amazing I have been pulling my hair out trying to figure this out. Thanks for providing an explanation... I'm going to break all of this down tonight and see if I can follow  along with what you were saying. Thanks so much!!!

Comment: Glad I could help Kelsey!